# Weird rounding issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, floating-point, decimal

Something very weird is happening with decimals and floating numbers and I can't understand why or where (ruby/rails/postgresql).

Given a *purchases* table with a decimal column - *total*:

```
p1 = Purchase.where(total: 5.99).first_or_create
p2 = Purchase.where(total: 5.99).first_or_create

[p1.id, p2.id] # => [1, 2]

p3 = Purchase.where(total: 5.99.to_d).first_or_create
p4 = Purchase.where(total: 5.99.to_d).first_or_create

[p3.id, p4.id] # => [1, 1]
```

Both Ruby and postgresql have no problem representing 5.99 exactly, no matter if decimals or floats:

```
5.99.to_s         # => "5.99"
5.99.to_d.to_s    # => "5.99"
5.99 == 5.99.to_d # => true

SELECT CAST(5.99 AS DECIMAL) AS decimal, CAST(5.99 AS FLOAT) AS float;
  #  decimal | float 
  # ---------+-------
  #     5.99 |  5.99
  # (1 row)

SELECT CAST(5.99 AS DECIMAL) = CAST(5.99 AS FLOAT) AS equal;
  #  equal 
  # -------
  #  t
  # (1 row)
```

To top it all off, this doesn't happen with some other values:

```
p5 = Purchase.where(total: 5.75).first_or_create
p6 = Purchase.where(total: 5.75).first_or_create
p7 = Purchase.where(total: 5.75.to_d).first_or_create

[p5.id, p6.id, p7.id] # => [3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Basically, you never want your `total` to ever be a floating point value anywhere, you'd want to be saying things like `'5.99'.to_d` instead.

Comment: @muistooshort, practical solutions are great, but answering a *why* question with *"don't do it"* is counter productive. You don't even know if they are same issue. Firstly, the other question starts with two different numbers. Secondly, two digit precision should be something that floats can handle without problem. Thirdly, you can see the problem is in Ruby there, while here we are not able to detect the issue (as shown in the examples).

Comment: @muistooshort, Please reopen this. The reason I created this question is because I want to get a greater understanding of what is happening. If I wanted a way for things to just work - I have already provided a solution in the question.

Comment: Sure but it is almost certainly exactly the same underlying problem: `BigDecimal` does weird things with some floats. The _why_ part is covered by all kinds of other floating point questions. I think you're mistaken about the "two digit precision" stuff, floats are internally represented in binary and some decimal representations cannot be represented in binary with full precision regardless of the _decimal_ precision, your `5.75` example can be because of the properties of `3/4`, `5.99` isn't so simple.

Comment: For reference: this was the duplicate: [Why are my BigDecimal objects initialized with unexpected rounding errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28295583/479863).

Comment: @muistooshort, *x does weird things with y* is such a blanket term. The issue in the other question was demonstrable to be reproducible inside Ruby, while here that is unclear. Thank you for being reasonable and reopening the question.

Comment: No binary floating point system can represent 5.99 exactly. The closest IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point value is 5.9900000000000002131628207280300557613372802734375

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, fair point, that is probably part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a regression in rails. It's reproducible with 5.0.0.1??? and is gone by 5.1.0.0???.

---

I bisected it and found [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/22042331650e943a1bb3f954fef7e2951e3ad2a3) to be the one that fixes the issue. This is the related [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27246).

The fix seems to be to stop using the pg gem's float encoder.